# Pass table and column names as parameters and retrieve value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to built generic query to pass column name I want to count on and table name I want to select value.

So far this is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenericCountAll]
    @TableName VARCHAR(100),
    @ColunName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE @Rowcount INT;

    SET @table = N'SELECT COUNT(' + @ColunName +') FROM ' + @TableName + '';
    EXEC(@table)

    SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    SELECT @Rowcount
END
```

Trying  to execute like this:

```
EXEC GenericCountAll 'T_User', 'Id';
```

but looks like I get two results, first result always returning a value of 1, and the second result returns the real count. Can anyone take a look?

Comment: The @@ROWCOUNT from your SELECT statement will /always/ be 1, surely? not sure what the point of that bit is. I imagine that's where the unwanted 1 is coming from.

Comment: @MandyShaw awaiting resolution as answer that i could mark. I am not sql developer. What i get is what i wrote. In my table i have 42 records, when i execute like this i get two results 1 and 42

Comment: Although I've posted an answer, you **must** read up on [SQL Injection](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=SQL+injection&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I can't stress that enough. What you have there is an incredibly dangerous way to construct dynamic SQL, it's a mistake you need to learn from, **now**.

Comment: @Arie Lamu's answer will not return the unwanted 1.

Comment: `@table varchar(30)` might be a little short for a variable, that is supposed to hold the concatenation of two `varchar(100)` and some other text. BTW, for object names you can use `sysname`. Nad `@@rowcount` is equal to 1 after a `SELECT count(*) FROM ...` as this always returns exactly one row.

Comment: "I am trying to built generic query" Well, don't. Create the queries you need for the tables you need, even if it means creating 10 `select count(x) from y` with different columns and different tables. The only way to create "generic" procedures like that is to use dynamic SQL and that comes with a price tag that includes SQL Injection vulnerability as demonstrated by Larnu's answer, perofmance hits, and lower readability which means herder maintenance (most cases).

Answer (score 5):

**Don't** create dynamic sql like that! Imagine if I ran:

```
EXEC GenericCountAll '*/DROP PROCEDURE dboGenericCountAll;--', '1);/*';
```

The resulting executed SQL would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(1);/*) FROM */ DROP PROCEDURE dboGenericCountAll;--
```

That would, quite simply, `DROP` your procedure. And that's just a simple example. If i knew I could keep doing malicious things, I might even be able to create a new login or user, and make the a `db_owner` or `sysadmin` (depending on the permissions of what ever is being used to run that procedure).

I don't know what the point of the `@@ROWCOUNT` is either, I doubt that's needed. Thus, to make this SAFE you would need to do something like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GenericCountAll]
    @TableName sysname, --Note the datatype change
    @ColumnName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SELECT  N'SELECT COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N') AS RowCount' + NCHAR(10) +
            N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N';'
    FROM sys.tables t
         JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
         JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE t.[name] = @TableName
      AND c.[name] = @ColumnName;
    /*
    If either the column or the table doesn't exist, then @SQL
    will have a value of NULL. This is a good thing, as it 
    is a great way to further avoid injection, if a bogus
    table or column name is passed
    */

    IF @SQL IS NOT NULL BEGIN;
        PRINT @SQL; --Your best debugging friend
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
    END ELSE BEGIN;
        RAISERROR(N'Table does not exist, or the Column does not exist for the Table provided.',11,1);
    END;

END
```

Comment: Good answer, although I would just use `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: @Larnu Questions: 1) Why NCHAR(10) ? 2) Is it possible to separate somehow real query from  additional query which is needed? 3) Would it be possible to show additional query which would get select * from that table? 4) Now when implemented your solution and when exeuting like this: EXEC GenericCountAll 'T_User', 'Id'; i get sql query string instead of value.

Comment: @Arie 1_ `NCHAR(10)` is a line break. When creating Dynamic SQL it's very helpful if you format it as well; putting it on on one line, or with poor use of white space, makes it very difficult to debug. 2) I have no idea what you mean by separating the "real" query; there are no "fakes" in that SQL. Can you try to explain a different way? 3) I'm not here to do you're work for you. It's important for you to be able to understand what I've done and use it for your own needs. 4) Are you looking at the messages? Don't forget, you're best friend in there too.

Comment: @Larnu Why there is AS RowCount? It is required?

Comment: @Arie I'm starting to get the idea that you're missing a lot of fundamentals of SQL. I can only explain so much of what it's doing here, but `AS` isn't something I expect to need to explain. `AS` is way of giving something an alias. Without `AS RowCount` you'd have a nameless column returned (not very useful).

Comment: @Larnu you right i am not sql expert just replacing my sickness coleague i am C developer. Last question if you don't mind: Let's say any error occurs in this SP e.g no table, no column or whatever else, is there anything that this SP can be done like catch exception and get it somehow from EXEC return?

Comment: @Arie yes you could do something. Like the comments say, of the table or column doesn't exist, then the variable `@SQL` will have a value of `NULL`. You could use an `IF...ELSE` to check the value of `@SQL` and then return an error instrad. If it has a value of `NULL`.

Comment: @Larnu, if the error occurs in the SQL batch that is unhandled in the T-SQL code, the error will be returned to the client where it can be handled as desired. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @DanGuzman I'd rather have dynamic SQL with a value of `NULL` than it inject. Is that what the downvote was for?

Comment: @Larnu, I can't speak for the downvote. You could use [`TRY/CATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) with `SELECT NULL in the CATCH block`.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather do the `IF...ELSE` and then use `RAISERROR`. There's no wrong answer here really though. I do, however, dislike a downvote without explanation. It's just common courtesy to explain your reason (unless others already have).

Comment: Added an `IF...ELSE` for checking if @SQL as the value `NULL`. If it does, an error is raised.